# Reading from barcode as one input

Tags: qt4, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an issue with `textChanged()` signal, basicly I am reading from barcode but unfortunately mine reads the barcode as series of input witch makes `textChanged()` emitted many times. Searching on the stackoverflow give me this two questions: [C# WinForm + Barcode Scanner input, TextChanged Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477202/c-sharp-winform-barcode-scanner-input-textchanged-error) and [Detecting when a barcode scanner ends input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928353/detecting-when-a-barcode-scanner-ends-input), the first solution I couldn't transfer the code to make it work for me(I don't code in C#), and the second sounds easy but I fail to read the ending line with my application:

connect(ui->matEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(GetEmployee(QString)));

```
void EmployeeDayLogger::GetEmployee(QString id)
{
    char c = id.toAscii();
    if(c == '\n')
    {
```

Compilation output:

```
..\..\..\Qt\Qt4.8.3\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h: In member function 'void EmployeeDayLogger::GetEmployee(QString)':
..\..\..\Qt\Qt4.8.3\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h:383: error: 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast() const' is private
..\employeedaylogger.cpp:152: error: within this context
```

Answer (score 0):

As your text field most likely will hold the whole barcode, try:

```
if (id.endsWith('\n'))
```